# How to exit a blocking call of recv() on a thread from a different thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, networking, pthreads

I have a code which runs two threads,

The first thread waits on the `sender` for data using `recv()` and then forwards the data to the `receiver` using `send`.

The second thread waits on the `receiver` for data using `recv()` and then forwards the data to the `sender` using `send`.

It is important that both of these work parallelly.

Suppose the sender disconnects, the first thread detects this and closes the connection.

How do I tell the second thread which is still waiting on the receiver that the connection has been closed and no further communication is required?

`recieve_packet` has been implemented using `recv()`.

`send_packet` has been implemented using `send()`.

`sender_fd` is the socket file descriptor of the sender.

`reciever_fd` is the socket file descriptor of the receiver.

```
void* sender_to_reciever(){
    int t1;packet* p = malloc(sizeof(packet));
    while((t1=recieve_packet(sender_fd,&p))!=0){
        send_packet(reciever_fd,p);
    }
    close(sender_fd);
}


void* reciever_to_sender(){
    int t1;packet* p = malloc(sizeof(packet));
    while((t1=recieve_packet(reciever_fd,&p))!=0){
        send_packet(sender_fd,p);
    }
    close(reciever_fd);
}
```

I don't want to change the implementation of the `send_packet` and `recieve_packet` function calls.

I tried closing both `sender_fd` and `reciever_d` if either while loop exits. It did not work, however.

Code for channel.c which handles both the sender and the reciever :-

```
#include "packets.c"


#define SERVER_PORT "8642"
#define QUEUE_LENGTH 10

void handle_connection(int);
void* sender_to_receiver();
void* receiver_to_sender();
int open_outgoing_connection(char*, char*);
int sender_fd;
int receiver_fd;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int sock_fd,new_fd,rv,yes;yes=1;
    struct addrinfo hints,*res;
    struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
    socklen_t addr_size;
    char client_details[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];


    struct sigaction sa;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    if((rv=getaddrinfo(NULL, SERVER_PORT, &hints, &res))!=0){
        printf("Error getaddrinfo : %s\n",gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }


    if((sock_fd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol))==-1){
        printf("Error socket file descriptor\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1){
        printf("Error setsockopt\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(bind(sock_fd,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen)==-1){
        close(sock_fd);
        printf("Error bind\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(listen(sock_fd, QUEUE_LENGTH)==-1){
        printf("Error listen\n");
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(res);

    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if(sigaction(SIGCHLD,&sa,NULL) == -1){
        printf("Error sigaction\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Now we have prepared the socket(ip+port) for accepting incoming connections.
    printf("Server PID : %d\n",getpid());
    while(1){
        addr_size = sizeof client_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addr_size);

        if(new_fd==-1){
            printf("Error Accepting Request %d\n",getpid());
            return 1;
        }

        inet_ntop(client_addr.ss_family,get_in_addr((struct sockaddr*)&client_addr),client_details,sizeof client_details);

        if(!fork()){ // Child Process
            close(sock_fd);
            printf("Connection Accepted From : %s by PID:%d\n",client_details,getpid());
            handle_connection(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 1;
}


void handle_connection(int socket_sender){
    packet* p = malloc(sizeof(packet));
    int t1;
    if((t1=receive_packet(socket_sender, &p))==0){
            printf("Closed Connection\n");
    }else{
        int socket_receiver;
        if((socket_receiver=open_outgoing_connection(p->destination_ip,p->destination_port))!=-1){      
            sender_fd = socket_sender;
            receiver_fd = socket_receiver;

            pthread_t str,rts;
            str     = pthread_self();
            rts   = pthread_self();

            pthread_create(&str,NULL,sender_to_receiver,NULL);
            pthread_create(&rts,NULL,receiver_to_sender,NULL);

            pthread_join(str,NULL);
            pthread_join(rts,NULL);

        }else{
            printf("Error Connecting to receiver\n");
        }
    }
}

void* sender_to_receiver(){
    int t1;packet* p = malloc(sizeof(packet));
    while((t1=receive_packet(sender_fd,&p))!=0){
        printf("SENDER\n");
        display_packet(p);
        send_packet(receiver_fd,p);
    }
    printf("Sender Disconnected\n");
    close(sender_fd);close(receiver_fd);
}
void* receiver_to_sender(){
    int t1;packet* p = malloc(sizeof(packet));
    while((t1=receive_packet(receiver_fd,&p))!=0){
        printf("Receiver\n");
        display_packet(p);
        send_packet(sender_fd,p);
    }
    printf("Receiver Disconnected\n");
    close(receiver_fd);close(sender_fd);
}

int open_outgoing_connection(char* ip, char* port){
    int gai;
    char server_ip[100];memset(server_ip,'\0',sizeof(server_ip));
    struct addrinfo hints,*server;
    memset(&hints,0,sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family     = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype   = SOCK_STREAM;
    int socket_fd;
    if((gai=getaddrinfo(ip,port,&hints,&server)) != 0){
        printf("GetAddrInfo Error: %s\n",gai_strerror(gai));
        return -1;
    }

    if((socket_fd = socket(server->ai_family, server->ai_socktype, server->ai_protocol)) == -1){
        printf("Socket Error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(connect(socket_fd,server->ai_addr,server->ai_addrlen) == -1){
        printf("Connect Error\n");
        return -1;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(server);
    inet_ntop(server->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr*)server->ai_addr), server_ip, sizeof(server_ip));
    printf("Connected to: %s\n",server_ip);
    return socket_fd;
}
```

Code for reciver:-

```
#include "packets.c"

#define QUEUE_LENGTH 10

void handle_connection(int);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    if(argc!=2){
        printf("Enter PORT\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int sock_fd,new_fd,rv,yes;yes=1;
    struct addrinfo hints,*res;
    struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
    socklen_t addr_size;
    char client_details[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];


    struct sigaction sa;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    if((rv=getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[1], &hints, &res))!=0){
        printf("Error getaddrinfo : %s\n",gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }


    if((sock_fd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol))==-1){
        printf("Error socket file descriptor\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1){
        printf("Error setsockopt\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(bind(sock_fd,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen)==-1){
        close(sock_fd);
        printf("Error bind\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(listen(sock_fd, QUEUE_LENGTH)==-1){
        printf("Error listen\n");
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(res);

    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if(sigaction(SIGCHLD,&sa,NULL) == -1){
        printf("Error sigaction\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Now we have prepared the socket(ip+port) for accepting incoming connections.
    printf("Server PID : %d\n",getpid());
    while(1){
        addr_size = sizeof client_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addr_size);

        if(new_fd==-1){
            printf("Error Accepting Request %d\n",getpid());
            return 1;
        }

        inet_ntop(client_addr.ss_family,get_in_addr((struct sockaddr*)&client_addr),client_details,sizeof client_details);

        if(!fork()){ // Child Process
            close(sock_fd);
            printf("Connection Accepted From : %s by PID:%d\n",client_details,getpid());
            handle_connection(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        close(new_fd);
    }
    return 1;
}



void handle_connection(int socket_fd){
    int t1;packet* p = malloc(sizeof(packet));
    while((t1=receive_packet(socket_fd,&p))!=0){
        display_packet(p);
        p->message = "ACK";
        p->timestamp = get_time_in_ns();
        send_packet(socket_fd,p);
    }
    printf("Sender Disconnected\n");
}
```

Code for Sender:-

```
#include "packets.c"

#define CHANNEL_PORT "8642"
#define CHANNEL_IP   "127.0.0.1"

int socket_fd;
char* destination_ip;
char* destination_port;
int number_of_packets;
char message[MESSAGE_BUFFER_LEN];


void prepare_packet_header(packet *p){
    p->destination_ip=destination_ip;
    p->destination_port=destination_port;
    p->timestamp = get_time_in_ns();
    p->length=0;
}


void divide_message_and_send_packets(){
    if(number_of_packets>strlen(message)){
        number_of_packets = strlen(message);
    }
    int indi_len = strlen(message)/number_of_packets;
    int lm = 0;int i,j;
    packet* all_packets[number_of_packets];

    for(i=0;i<number_of_packets;i+=1)all_packets[i]=malloc(sizeof(packet));
    // HANDSHAKE
    prepare_packet_header(all_packets[0]);
    all_packets[0]->message="SYN";
    all_packets[0]->uid=-1;
    send_packet(socket_fd,all_packets[0]);
    // HANDSHAKE OVER
    for(i=0;i<number_of_packets;i+=1){
        // printf("Processing Packet: %d with message[%d:%d]\n",i,lm,lm+indi_len);
        if(i!=number_of_packets-1){
            char temp[indi_len+1];memset(temp,'\0', sizeof temp);
            for(j=lm;j<lm+indi_len;j+=1)temp[j-lm]=message[j];
            all_packets[i]->message = malloc(sizeof temp);
            strcpy(all_packets[i]->message, temp);
            all_packets[i]->uid = i;
        }else{
            char temp[strlen(message)-lm+1];memset(temp,'\0', sizeof temp);
            for(j=lm;j<strlen(message);j+=1)temp[j-lm]=message[j];
            all_packets[i]->message = malloc(sizeof temp);
            strcpy(all_packets[i]->message, temp);
            all_packets[i]->uid = i;
        }
        prepare_packet_header(all_packets[i]);lm+=indi_len;
        display_packet(all_packets[i]);
        send_packet(socket_fd,all_packets[i]);
    }

}

void main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    if(argc!=5){
        printf("Enter DESTINATION_IP DESTINATION_PORT NUMBER_OF_PACKETS MESSAGE\n");
        return;
    }

    strcpy(message,argv[4]);
    number_of_packets=atoi(argv[3]);
    destination_ip=malloc(sizeof argv[1] + 1);memset(destination_ip,'\0', sizeof destination_ip);
    destination_port=malloc(sizeof argv[2] + 1);memset(destination_port,'\0', sizeof destination_port);
    strcpy(destination_ip,argv[1]);
    strcpy(destination_port,argv[2]);
    int gai;
    char server_ip[100];memset(server_ip,'\0',sizeof(server_ip));
    struct addrinfo hints,*server;
    memset(&hints,0,sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family     = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype   = SOCK_STREAM;

    if((gai=getaddrinfo(CHANNEL_IP,CHANNEL_PORT,&hints,&server)) != 0){
        printf("GetAddrInfo Error: %s\n",gai_strerror(gai));
        return;
    }

    if((socket_fd = socket(server->ai_family, server->ai_socktype, server->ai_protocol)) == -1){
        printf("Socket Error\n");
    }

    if(connect(socket_fd,server->ai_addr,server->ai_addrlen) == -1){
        printf("Connect Error\n");
    }
    freeaddrinfo(server);
    inet_ntop(server->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr*)server->ai_addr), server_ip, sizeof(server_ip));
    printf("Connected to: %s\n",server_ip);

    divide_message_and_send_packets();
    while(1){} // busy wait taht simulates future work
}
```

Code for packets.c (Contains functions related to the packets):-

```
#include "helper.c"

typedef struct StupidAssignment{
    long length;
    char* destination_ip;
    char* destination_port;
    long timestamp;
    long uid;
    char* message;
}packet;

int receive_packet(int socket,packet** p1){
    packet* p = *p1;
    int remaining=0;int i;
    int received=0;
    long content_length=0;
    remaining=11;
    char buffer[MESSAGE_BUFFER_LEN];memset(buffer,'\0',sizeof(buffer));
    while(remaining>0){
        int t1 = recv(socket, buffer+received, remaining, 0);
        if(t1==0)return 0;
        remaining-=t1;
        received+=t1;
    }
    content_length = read_long(buffer, received);

    received=0;
    remaining=content_length;p->length=content_length;
    memset(buffer,'\0',sizeof(buffer));
    while(remaining>0){
        int t1 = recv(socket, buffer+received, remaining, 0);
        if(t1==0)return 0;
        remaining-=t1;
        received+=t1;
    }

    char part[MESSAGE_BUFFER_LEN];memset(part,'\0',sizeof(part));int part_len=0;int nlmkr=0;
    for(i=0;i<=content_length;i+=1){
        if(buffer[i]=='\n' || i==content_length){
            nlmkr+=1;
            if(nlmkr==1)    read_char(&(p->destination_ip), part, part_len);
            else if(nlmkr==2)   read_char(&(p->destination_port), part, part_len);
            else if(nlmkr==3)   p->timestamp = read_long(part, part_len);
            else if(nlmkr==4)   p->uid = read_long(part, part_len);
            else if(nlmkr==6)   read_char(&(p->message), part, part_len);
            part_len=0;memset(part, '\0', sizeof part);

        }else{
            part[part_len++]=buffer[i];
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void send_packet(int socket,packet *p){
    char temp[MESSAGE_BUFFER_LEN];memset(temp,'\0',sizeof temp);
    strcat(temp,p->destination_ip);strcat(temp,"\n");
    strcat(temp,p->destination_port);strcat(temp,"\n");
    snprintf(temp+strlen(temp),100,"%ld\n",p->timestamp);
    snprintf(temp+strlen(temp),100,"%ld\n",p->uid);
    // write_long(p->timestamp,temp);strcat(temp,"\n");
    // write_long(p->uid,temp);strcat(temp,"\n");
    strcat(temp,"\n");
    strcat(temp,p->message);
    char buffer[MESSAGE_BUFFER_LEN];memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof buffer);
    p->length = strlen(temp);
    snprintf(buffer,100,"%10ld\n",strlen(temp));
    strcat(buffer, temp);
    sendAll(buffer,socket);
}

void display_packet(packet* p){
    printf("----PACKET START----\n");
    printf("%ld\n",p->length);
    printf("%s\n",p->destination_ip);
    printf("%s\n",p->destination_port);
    printf("%ld\n",p->timestamp);
    printf("%ld\n",p->uid);
    printf("%s\n",p->message);
    printf("----PACKET END-----\n");
}
```

Code for helper.c (Some functions used by all the other codes):-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MESSAGE_BUFFER_LEN 20480

void read_char(char** into, char* from, int length){
    *into = malloc(length+1);memset(*into, '\0', sizeof *into);
    strcpy(*into, from);
    // printf("%s\n",into);
}

long read_long(char* from, int length){
    int i;long temp=0;
    for(i=0;i<length;i+=1){
        if(isdigit(*(from+i))){
            temp=temp*10;temp+=(long)(*(from+i) - '0');         
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

void write_long(long t1,char* m){
    int mkr=0;
    char temp[100];memset(temp,'\0',sizeof temp);
    while(t1!=0){
        temp[mkr] = ((int)(t1%10)) + '0';
        t1 = t1/10;
    }
    for(mkr=strlen(temp)-1;mkr>=0;mkr-=1){
        *(m+strlen(m))=temp[mkr];
    }
}

void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr* sa){
    if(sa->sa_family == AF_INET){
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in *)sa)->sin_addr);
    }else{
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
    }
}


void sigchld_handler(int s){
    int saved_errno=errno;
    while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);
    errno = saved_errno;
}

int sendAll(char* data_to_send,int socket_fd){
    int bytesleft = strlen(data_to_send);
    int total=0;int n;
    while(bytesleft>0){
        n = send(socket_fd,data_to_send + total, bytesleft, 0);
        if(n==-1)break;
        total+=n;
        bytesleft-=n;
    }
    return n==-1?-1:0;
}

long get_time_in_ns(){
    struct timespec start;clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&start);
    long ct = ((long)start.tv_sec)*1e9 + ((long)start.tv_nsec);
    return ct;
}
```

The code isn't documented at all.

Comment: We cannot answer the question without the implementations of `send_packet` and `receive_packet`, and, separately, there might well not be any good solution without modifying those.  It is suspicious, however, that you do not make any attempt to detect error conditions.  It is possible that that is why closing the sockets did not achieve what you wanted.

Comment: Send Packet converts the packet structure into a desirable format and transmits all the bytes. Receive Packet received the first 10 bytes which hold the length and then keeps receiving until all the data is received and then stores it in the packet structure pointed to by *p. The code is mostly is a mess but I did return 0 from receive_packet if any of the recv() calls inside it returned 0.

Comment: What if when the sender disconnects, I send a goodbye packet of some sort to the receiver that indicates that it should send back a closing signal to the recv() function on the other thread by closing the socket file.That would work right?

Comment: Shutdown the socket for input. That will unblock the `recv()` and cause it to return zero, as though the peer had disconnected. But telling us what you *think* your code does is completely pointless. What we need is the actual code.

Comment: I tried shutting down both the sockets if either disconnected, it didn't work though.

Comment: But did you try shutting it down to *for input?* It most certainly does work.

Comment: I'll try to do that now.

Comment: I added the code.I'm sorry if it's illegible and thanks for the shutdown command. I'll use it in just a second.

Comment: It works perfectly. Can you tell me the difference between `close(socket)` and `shutdown(socket,SHUT_RDWR)` and write an answer I can accept.

Comment: @asds_asds The `close(socket)` function releases a resource. You *must not* release a resource in one thread while another thread is, or might be, accessing it. The results can be disastrous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For TCP, call `shutdown` on the socket. To be more complete:

1. Set some flag that the thread will check so it will know that a shutdown is in process when it becomes unblocked.
2. Do whatever you need to do to shut the connection down, ultimately calling `shutdown` on the socket when you're done. If you need to call `shutdown` as part of your teardown process, do it. If not, when you're done with your teardown process (if any) `shutdown` the connection in both directions.
3. Do not, under any circumstances, call `close` on the socket until you can 100% confirm that no thread is, or might be, trying to access the socket. This is extremely important.

For UDP, send a datagram to the socket. That will unblock the thread as it receives the dummy datagram.